# How to crate randomized list name in Jmeter and using in different threads - Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a question about global variable in Jmeter.
I want to create a list in the first thread, and use the list in all threads.
since it is global, I want that each time I run the test planm the string name will get new value. 
I created a function that generates uniqe names, but when I try to call it in second thread it is not know the name of the variable.

The test plan
[image]

First  Jssr preprocess to create randomized name to use as variable.
[image]

2. the sampler where I put the value, and save global variable t_${offer_list_rand}, that will point for the list

[image]

3. try in different thread to call for the list pointer t_${offer_list_rand} and try to add value to the list

[image]

exception in console

```
Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: offer_list_rand for class: Script30
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: offer_list_rand for class: Script30
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: offer_list_rand for class: Script30
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:66) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:310) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at Script30.run(Script30.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    ... 9 more
```

4. As you can see the offer_list_rand variable created

[image]

I just want to create a List with name that will be randomized in each time I run the test plan, and call it from different thread.
Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recheck this is the solution.
in the Jssr pre processor I put

```
String list_rand = list_obj.get_random_list_name("temp_");
props.put('list_rand',list_rand);
```

and in the processor I put

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

props.put('list_rand_'+ props.get('list_rand'),list2);
```

when I want in other threadgroup to call it I used

```
List<String> myList = props.get('list_rand'+ props.get('list_rand'));


myList.add("333");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter's best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) use `vars.get` inside script instead of `${}`:

```
 props.put("t_" + vars.get("offer_list_rand"),offer_list);
```

Comment: After using in first thread group props.put("t_" + vars.get("offer_list_rand"),offer_list);                           and in the second thread group         List<String> myList2 = props.get("t_" + vars.get("offer_list_rand"));   and try to add values to myList2   myList2.add("2");                   I get this exception

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method add() on null object
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method add() on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something weird

1. Your Groovy script will not work as you cannot refer `offer_list_rand` variable as `${offer_list_rand}`, going forward consider using `Parameters` section for any [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) references inside Groovy scripts
2. Your approach will not work as 2nd [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) will know nothing about `${offer_list_rand}` variable value as JMeter Variables are local to Thread Groups. Technically you can have JMeter Property named as the JMeter Variable like:

   ```
   vars.put('offer_list_rand', 'foo')
   props.put('offer_list_rand', 'bar')
   ```

   and you will have **different** objects with different values, the variable will be `foo` and visible in the Thread Group where it was defined and the property will be `bar` and it will be visible to the whole JVM until you turn off or restart JMeter.
3. It is always faster/easier/better to use JMeter built-in test elements (or plugins) rather than go for scripting, in particular your case you can easily go for [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function or [Inter-Thread Communication](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) plugin or even move your logic into normal Thread Group out of setUp Thread Group and make it to run only once using [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) or [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

Comment: Hey Dimitri,  what you suggest is that each time to restart Jmeter? each time I want to debug restart Jmeter? each run restart Jmeter? I want to create a list each time I start the test plan, put it in the first thread group, and call it in other threads. why for this scenario each time I need to restart Jmeter? why I can not create string with random name, and in each time I run to create different list?your solution is to use the same name, and if I will add values to the list in the first time I ran Jmeter, and than stop and rerun Jmeter it will uses values from the first run? I want each

Comment: Run will be from scratch,

Comment: Is their any way, any way in Jmeter to create list of string and use it in all threads in test plan. moreover that in each time I run the test plan, the list will start from nothing, and not saved values from previews run? without any restarting and other fatigue ways?